# SQL Join Query Returning Null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I've got a query that references three tables.

The tables are as follows:

**FORM_FACTOR**

```
FORM_FACTOR_ID | FORM_FACTOR_DESCRIPTION
```

**AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE**

```
SO_LINE_NUMBER | FORM_FACTOR_ID
```

**AOF_ORDER_PARTS**

```
SERIAL_NUMBER | SO_LINE_NUMBER
```

The idea is to get the `FORM_FACTOR_DESCRIPTION` using the `SERIAL_NUMBER` of the part. I wrote a query to do that, but for whatever reason it's returning null. I could swear this query was working, but apparently there is a flaw. Help is appreciated.

The query:

```
DECLARE @serial VARCHAR(50)
SET @serial = 'somestring'

SELECT 
    ff.[FORM_FACTOR_DESCRIPTION] 
FROM
    [dbo].[FORM_FACTOR] AS ff
JOIN 
    [dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] AS lQ ON ff.[FORM_FACTOR_ID] = lQ.[FORM_FACTOR_ID]
JOIN
    [dbo].[AOF_ORDER_PARTS] AS oO ON oO.[SO_LINE_NUMBER] = lQ.[SO_LINE_NUMBER]
WHERE 
    oO.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = @serial
```

Comment: It is probably returning no rows, as opposed to `NULL`.  The most likely reason is that the `WHERE` has no matches.  The next most likely reasons are that the `JOIN`s have no matches.

Comment: Are you not missing a SET or SELECT command from the beginning of the second line?  In other words SET @serial = 'something';

Comment: Either @serial doesn't exist in AOF_Order_parts; or it does and the so_Line_Number it associates doens't exist in lq.form_factor_ID, or it does  but the form_Facotr_ID doens't exist in ff.  This seems to be a data problem not a query.

Comment: Give us some data and we can tell you... Query is technically sound but now way of knowing why it's not pulling anything without seeing your data

Comment: The query looks fine.  Replace your joins with Left joins and add a column from every table.  You'll probably see that somewhere there's no match on the join condition, and as a result the query in total is returning no rows.

Comment: @RichardHansell yes, a set.  THis is not verbatim.  It's shortened for this post :)

Comment: Check your data in all the table for particular SERIAL_NUMBER you might be missing some data in table

Comment: What is the type of SERIAL_NUMBER?

Comment: @sepupic VARCHAR(50)

Comment: Does `select * from [dbo].[AOF_ORDER_PARTS] WHERE [SERIAL_NUMBER] = @serial` return something?

Comment: `SELECT [FORM_FACTOR_DESCRIPTION] FROM [dbo].[FORM_FACTOR] WHERE [FORM_FACTOR_ID] = 1;
SELECT [FORM_FACTOR_ID] FROM [dbo].[AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE] WHERE [SO_LINE_NUMBER] = '43955'
SELECT [SO_LINE_NUMBER] FROM [dbo].[AOF_ORDER_PARTS] WHERE [SERIAL_NUMBER] = 'EOXH2T100008'`  Running this fails on the 3rd query.  I have no idea why though because the data absolutely exists.

Comment: @sepupic it looks like it's failing to get the [SO_LINE_NUMBER] from the final table with the where clause.

Comment: It's very strange.  I can't query that table at all using that serial as a reference.

Comment: Remove the `WHERE` condition and use `SELECT *` to see what are you getting from the `JOIN`

Comment: But I can select * and everything is there.  Wtf is going on.  I've done this a million times with no troubles!  Haha

Comment: possibly a trimming issue?

Comment: Not real sure, going to have to dig a lot deeper it seems.

Comment: Doesn't merit a full answer, but why don't you try using `like`? Might help a little

Comment: What's the type of [SERIAL_NUMBER] ?  varchar or nvarchar? Are you certain that the "EOXH2T100008" you say is in the table contains only ascii characters? And no spaces before it?

Comment: @LukStorms I've already stated its VARCHAR(50).  Definetly no spaces.  I copied the cell from SSMS, and pasted it between single quotes to test.  Something is broken, just don't know what yet.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that line. And since you checked it then i assume it's also not something silly as confusing a O with a 0.

Comment: @LukStorms I wish :D

Comment: Joining on a sales order line number, without a sales order number, will likely produce lots of results you don't want, and is also likely what's affecting your query. If your company has 1 million sales orders, there are 1 million results with sales order line number of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Not really a solution here. It still remains an unsolved mystery at this point.

But to look for the root cause, perhaps you could turn the joins around and use left joins?
Perhaps it's then easier to spot at what point the joins return NULL on the right side.

In the example below I messed around with COLLATION. 
Just ignore and remove it, most likely it has nothing to do with it.

```
DECLARE @serial VARCHAR(50);
SET @serial = 'EOXH2T100008' ;

SELECT DB_NAME() as current_db, DATABASEPROPERTYEX(DB_NAME(), 'Collation') as db_collation;
--#SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
--SELECT Name, Description FROM fn_helpcollations() where name like '%Latin1%' ;

declare @FORM_FACTOR table (FORM_FACTOR_ID int, FORM_FACTOR_DESCRIPTION varchar(30));
insert into @FORM_FACTOR (FORM_FACTOR_ID, FORM_FACTOR_DESCRIPTION) values (1,'test 1'),(2,'test 2');

declare @AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE table (ORDER_LINE_QUEUE_ID int identity(1,1), FORM_FACTOR_ID int, SO_LINE_NUMBER int);
insert into @AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE (FORM_FACTOR_ID, SO_LINE_NUMBER) values (1,100),(3,100),(2,200);

declare @AOF_ORDER_PARTS table (ORDER_PARTS_ID int identity(1,1), SO_LINE_NUMBER int, SERIAL_NUMBER VARCHAR(50) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_BIN); 
insert into @AOF_ORDER_PARTS (SO_LINE_NUMBER, SERIAL_NUMBER) values (100,'EOXH2T100008'),(200,'eOXH2T100008');

SELECT
oO.ORDER_PARTS_ID, oO.SERIAL_NUMBER, oO.SO_LINE_NUMBER, 
lQ.ORDER_LINE_QUEUE_ID, lQ.FORM_FACTOR_ID, 
ff.FORM_FACTOR_DESCRIPTION
FROM @AOF_ORDER_PARTS AS oO
LEFT JOIN @AOF_ORDER_LINE_QUEUE AS lQ ON lQ.[SO_LINE_NUMBER] = oO.[SO_LINE_NUMBER]
LEFT JOIN @FORM_FACTOR AS ff ON ff.[FORM_FACTOR_ID] = lQ.[FORM_FACTOR_ID]
WHERE oO.[SERIAL_NUMBER] = @serial;
```